# Devise skip_confirmation! fails to avoid to send the confirmation instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

My app is set up so that if a user signs in with Oauth or Openid, they don't have to confirm their email address.  However, Devise is still sending email confirmations.  When I call User.skip_confirmation! I get an undefined method error.  My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, 
  :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :token_authenticatable, :omniauthable

  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
      user
    else 
      #User.skip_confirmation!
      User.create!(:username => data.name, :email => data.email, :password =>    Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
  end

  def skip_confirmation!
   self.confirmed_at = Time.now
 end
end
```

My Controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in @user
      @fname = @user.username
      redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "Welcome #{@fname}!" }
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Since you are already using :confirmable you don't really need the `skip_confirmation!` message (http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#skip_confirmation%21-instance_method)
Could you post the stack-trace? I doubt it's the `skip_confirmation!` method that's missing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to skip confirmation before you create the User objects and its persisted to the database. So the user creation part of your method would look like

```
user = User.new(:username => data.name, :email => data.email, :password =>    Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

Comment: That worked after I changed user.save to user.create.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you also need to add 'user' as the last line so it will remain the return value of the function

Comment: Hi Rishav, I have exactly the same code in user.rb, still my app sends out the confirmation emails when I authorize it in Facebook. Any idea why user.skip_confirmation! is not doing anything?

Comment: @LaszloTenki - Its hard to suggest a solution without looking at your code. It might be something small that you might be missing.

Answer (score 13):

If you're updating a user record, make sure to use `skip_reconfirmation!` (mind the **re**)