# How to get Devise in Rails skip_confirmation to actually not send an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

I've been trying to seed users to test out my Rails site and ran into the issue that on saving the user, my setup would send out a confirmation email. Multiply that times 100 dummy users and you have a problem. Rails documentation and SO led me to `skip_confirmation!`, along the following lines [0]:

```
user = User.new(:username => name, :email => email, :password =>    password)
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

However, (surprise surprise) this still sent out an email with every save. How can I get Devise to stop doing this?

[0] https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673771/4283301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise's `#skip_confirmation!` is misleading. It says "If you don't want confirmation to be sent on create, neither a code to be generated, call skip_confirmation!."

Really what I was looking for in this case was `#skip_confirmation_notification!`. The documentation makes the distinction that this "Skips sending the confirmation/reconfirmation notification email after_create/after_update."

This works! To get the above code to not send out a confirmation email, it should look like this:

```
user = User.new(:username => name, :email => email, :password =>    password)
user.skip_confirmation_notification!
user.save
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply remove `:confirmable` from the code below in your user.rb file

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :async
```

In your test environment `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method` should be set to `:test`, which means that these emails will not be sent out.

Comment: The goal is email confirmations in production and development but not testing - removing :confirmable removes email confirmations across all environments